# What is the correct way to catch both Error and Exception following `effective dart`?

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, error-handling, dart-analyzer

this code sample

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  const one = 1;
  String oneAsString() => one as String;

  test('Make sure it fails', () {
    var s;
    var _e;
    try {
      s = oneAsString();
    } on Error catch (e) {
      _e = e;
    }
    expect(s == null, true, reason: 'should fail');
    expect(_e == null, false, reason: 'error or exception should be returned');
  });

  test('Catchin Error', () {
    var _e;
    try {
      oneAsString();
    } on Error catch (e) {
      _e = e;
    }
    expect(_e is Error, true, reason: 'should be an error');
  });

  test('Catchin Exception', () {
    var _e;
    try {
      oneAsString();
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      _e = e;
    }

    expect(_e is Exception, true, reason: 'should be an exception');
  });

  test('Why not BOTH', () {
    var _e;
    try {
      oneAsString();
    } on Error catch (e) {
      _e = e;
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      _e = e;
    }

    expect(_e is Error, true, reason: 'should be an error');
    expect(_e is Exception, false, reason: 'should NOT be an exception');
  });
}
```

outputs this result

```sh
00:02 +2 -1: Catchin Exception [E]                                                                                                                                                                          
  type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
  test/widget_test.dart 5:31   main.oneAsString
  test/widget_test.dart 31:18  main.<fn>
  
00:02 +3 -1: Some tests failed.
```

the safest approach seems to be `Why not BOTH`, but following [effective dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart)
(enforcing it with the package [effective_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/effective_dart))
the analysis complains about  [avoid_catching_errors](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_catching_errors.html)

> DON'T explicitly catch Error or types that implement it.
>
> Errors differ from Exceptions in that Errors can be analyzed and
> prevented prior to runtime. It should almost never be necessary to
> catch an error at runtime.
>
> BAD:
>
> try {   somethingRisky(); } on Error catch(e) {   doSomething(e); }
> GOOD:
>
> try {   somethingRisky(); } on Exception catch(e) {   doSomething(e);
> }

and if I simple do

```dart
try {} catch (e) {}
```

the analyzer complains about [avoid_catches_without_on_clauses](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_catches_without_on_clauses.html)

> AVOID catches without on clauses.
>
> Using catch clauses without on clauses make your code prone to
> encountering unexpected errors that won't be thrown (and thus will go
> unnoticed).
>
> BAD:
>
> try {  somethingRisky() } catch(e) {   doSomething(e); } GOOD:
>
> try {  somethingRisky() } on Exception catch(e) {   doSomething(e); }

what is the correct approach to catch BOTH [Error](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Error-class.html) and [Exception](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Exception-class.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re-posting the answer from `@Miyoyo` on [r/FlutterDev](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/) [discord](https://discord.gg/uMya6wQ)

```
Optimally? You do not catch error
Just, at all
Remember effective dart is Guidelines
Using them as gospel will make some things impossible
Catching error is deliberately made to be "not according to guidelines"
```

because you're not supposed to do that

for my use case I'll just add

`// ignore_for_file: avoid_catching_errors`